# Date calculating from 3 field

Tags: jquery, forms, datepicker, timestamp

I have 3 field in my form. One field with datepacker and two with select fields for hour and minute. Is there any possibilities to convert data from these 3 field to timestamp?

```
<label for="date_from">Date *</label>
<input type="text" size="20" id="date_from" name="[date_from]" value="" readonly="readonly" />

<label for="time_from_hour">Hour: </label>
<select id="time_from_hour" name="[time_from_hour]" class="select">
    <option value="">---</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="19">19</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="22">22</option>
    <option value="23">23</option>
</select>
<span> : </span>

<label for="time_from_minute" style="display: none;">Minute: </label>
<select id="time_from_minute" name="[time_from_minute]" class="select">
    <option value="">---</option>
    <option value="00">00</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="45">45</option>
</select>
```

Sorry for my English :P

Thanks for any help.

Comment: check out [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: What is the format of the date ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the date that you get is in the format `mm/dd/yyy hh:mm` then you can try the following code

```
var myDate="7/23/2012 10:03";
myDate=myDate.split("/");
var newDate=myDate[1]+","+myDate[0]+","+myDate[2];
var timestamp = (new Date(newDate).getTime()/1000);
```

You may have to make changes to suit your requirement

Answer (score 0):

This could be of some help 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

and you can always user `formatDate` to have printable data.